# Projection outline of object to other object in scenekit

Tags: scenekit, projection

Hello~ I want to draw outline of cube on capsule surface. It is outline through normal between camera and cube center. That image is made by unity but I wnat to render on ios scenekit. Do you have good way to do this simply??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC14C.jpg)

Comment: Draw outline = You want to place an SCNBox somewhere near your capsule or you want to texture map the capsule with an image of a cube?

Comment: @Voltan Yeah It is good way that makes capsure texture from outline of the cube or makes new object like the outline.

Comment: Please define capture texture?  Could you edit your question and supply more details, thx